# How to make OpenCv on Python play video that is already played from web cam?

Tags: python, opencv

Essentially I need a loop inside of a loop, so the live-video could be played using another live-video as a reference. Is it, for example, possible to save video on hardware and then play it from there in real time? If yes, then how? I have a code with an attempt to meake something similar below. ORB detector shouldn`t affect the process.

```
import cv2
width = 640
height = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))
while True:

    frame_read = cap
    (ret, myFrame) = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(myFrame, (width, height))
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp = orb.detect(img, None)
    (kp, des) = orb.compute(img, kp)
    img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, img, color=(0xFF, 0, 0xFF))
    img2 = cv2.flip(img2, 0)
    out.write(img2)

    cv2.imshow('test', img2)

    while True:
        test = cap.open('output.avi')

        frame_read = test
        (ret, kpFrame) = test.read()
        img3 = cv2.resize(kpFrame, (width, height))
        cv2.imshow('test2', img3)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you provided?

Comment: I get an error 
(ret, kpFrame) = test.read()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'read'